# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError while integrating firebase performance library in react native app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to integrate the firebase performance library into my react native application. I am following the documentation at https://rnfirebase.io/perf/usage

I am getting java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError error after adding the below line to /android/build.gradle

`classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'`

Following is the complete error message:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':amazon-cognito-identity-js'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/firebase/perf/plugin/FirebasePerfPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Following is my gradle version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
```

Following is the java version on my machine:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

Any idea what the issue can be?

Answer (score 22):

I solved this by changing the JDK runtime from 1.8 to 11 in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Gradle JDK.

Comment: or if you're using `expo`, then make sure `java -version` returns the version `11` :)